# How to make message input toolbar float at the bottom of UINavigationController, like Messages app?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uitextview

I've searched around and I haven't found a good solution for this.

While `UINavigationController` has a `UIToolbar` hidden that is built-in, there are a few different issues with putting a `UITextView` in it for multi-line text input... which resizes accurately to a maximum height after a few different lines are added. It's not a natural fit for `UIToolbar`, even when putting it in as a custom view item. There are numerous issues.

If one wants to put a message input with a "send" button that floats at the bottom of a `UINavigationController`'s child `UIViewController` (which perhaps has a `UIScrollView` for messages inside of it) ... How would one go about  doing that? Basically, the goal is to clone the iMessage/Messages app's bottom send bar.

[image: screenshot of <code>Messages</code> app input bar]

Some of the solutions have talked about making it the `inputAccessoryView` or something, but that disappears when the keyboard is hidden. Having two of those (one under the other) seems terrible.

**With so many messaging apps on the App Store,** surely there must be a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `inputAccessoryView` for the `UIViewController` as in the example of this Cocoa Pod is the only thing I've found that works: https://github.com/datwelk/RDRGrowingTextView